# Why when generating a maze the grid is not really 10x10 size?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For example in the Inspector i set the Width and Height values to 10. So the grid should be 10x10 But when i'm running the game it's changing the values of the Width and Height in the inspector to 11 both to 11. And then when i look at the scene view and counting the width and height i see they are both 9. Like 9x9 grid, not 10x10 and not 11x11.

Then later if i click the button i created to generate a new maze each time then if i set the width and height both to 5 the grid size will be 4x4 and if i set both to 6x6 the grid size will be 5x5

For some reason the value i enter for width and height he reduce it by one. And i want to make it in the size of the values. For example 10x10 so the grid will be 10x10.

This is a screenshot while the game is running. you can see on the right in the inspector i changed the values to 5 and 5 and clicked the button. But in the scene view you can count the size of the grid: it's 4x4

It's showing only the maze but you can imagine and count how the grid should be and see it's not 5x5 but 4x4

[image: Grid]

This is another screenshot of 5x5 this time the grid seems like size of 3x3 Maybe i don't understand how it's working and how it should work ?

[image: Grid]

This is a link for the tutorial i'm trying to make:

[Maze tutorial](http://tutorials.daspete.at/unity3d/maze-runner/chapter-01)

This is the scripts i'm using so far:

Maze class for all settings and generating:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Maze
{
    //Grid size
    public int width;
    public int height;

    //Store grid
    private bool[,] grid;
    //Generate random directions to move
    private System.Random rg;

    //Start position
    int startX;
    int startY;

    //Public getter
    public bool[,] Grid
    {
        get { return grid; }
    }

    //Constructor of the grid for setting values
    public Maze(int width, int height, System.Random rg)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        this.rg = rg;
    }

    //Generate the grid
    public void Generate()
    {
        grid = new bool[width, height];

        startX = 1;
        startY = 1;

        grid[startX, startY] = true;

        MazeDigger(startX, startY);
    }

    void MazeDigger(int x, int y)
    {
        int[] directions = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        //We create random array of directions
        HelpingTools.Shuffle(directions, rg);

        //We are looping over all the directions
        for (int i = 0; i < directions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (directions[i] == 1)
            {
                if (y - 2 <= 0)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x, y - 2] == false)
                {
                    grid[x, y - 2] = true;
                    grid[x, y - 1] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x, y - 2);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 2)
            {
                if (x - 2 <= 0)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x - 2, y] == false)
                {
                    grid[x - 2, y] = true;
                    grid[x - 1, y] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x - 2, y);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 3)
            {
                if (x + 2 >= width - 1)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x + 2, y] == false)
                {
                    grid[x + 2, y] = true;
                    grid[x + 1, y] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x + 2, y);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 4)
            {
                if (y + 2 >= height - 1)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x, y + 2] == false)
                {
                    grid[x, y + 2] = true;
                    grid[x, y + 1] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x, y + 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This class create random array of the maze:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HelpingTools : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static T[] Shuffle<T>(T[] array, System.Random rg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = rg.Next(i, array.Length);

            T tempItem = array[randomIndex];

            array[randomIndex] = array[i];
            array[i] = tempItem;
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

This is the maze generator class

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MazeGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Maze maze;
    public int mazeWidth;
    public int mazeHeight;
    public string mazeSeed;
    public GameObject wallPrefab;

    private GameObject wall;
    private GameObject wallCorner;
    private System.Random mazeRG;
    private GameObject[] bricks;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        mazeRG = new System.Random();

        if (mazeWidth % 2 == 0)
            mazeWidth++;

        if (mazeHeight % 2 == 0)
        {
            mazeHeight++;
        }

        maze = new Maze(mazeWidth, mazeHeight, mazeRG);
        GenerateMaze();
    }

    public void GenerateMaze()
    {
        bricks = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("MazeBrick");
        if (bricks.Length > 0)
            DestroyMaze();

        maze.Generate();
        DrawMaze();
    }

    private void DestroyMaze()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < bricks.Length; i++)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(bricks[i]);
        }
    }

    void DrawMaze()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, 0.5f, y);

                if (maze.Grid[x, y] == true)
                {
                    CreateMaze(position, transform, 0, mazeRG.Next(0, 3) * 90);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void CreateMaze(Vector3 position, Transform parent, int sortingOrder, float rotation)
    {
        GameObject mazePrefab = Instantiate(wallPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        mazePrefab.transform.SetParent(parent);
        mazePrefab.transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotation);
        mazePrefab.tag = "MazeBrick";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

This is the button script@

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(MazeGenerator))]
public class GenerateButton : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        MazeGenerator myScript = (MazeGenerator)target;
        if (GUILayout.Button("Generate Maze"))
        {
            myScript.GenerateMaze();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the grid size not fit to the result when running the game. The Maze is fine but the grid not seems to be 10x10 or 5x5 or 6x6

If for example i wanted to draw the completed grid not only the random maze then how can i do it and what would be the size ?

Again maybe i didn't understand how it is working and should be working.

Comment: Well, it does what you have coded. See MazeGenerator.Start method

Comment: @SirRufo i saw it. Even if in the Start for testing i'm not using the lines mazeWidth++; and mazeHeight++; and i see that on the line maze = new Maze(mazeWidth, mazeHeight, mazeRG); both mazeWidth and mazeHeight values are 5 the grid is still created as 3x3

Comment: Use the debugger and examine what maze size is really used. It is impossible to determine the real used maze size just from the maze representation on the screen

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)` What happens if you remove `- 1`?

Comment: Did removing `-1` help @jdoedoedoedoe ?

Answer (score 0):

MazeGenerator.Start() function makes even dimension odd by incrementing it.

Then you spawn your maze inversed - cells with true value should be empty and cells with false value should be filled with walls.